# RewriteRule .htaccess routing some links

Tags: .htaccess, routes

I have almost no understanding of .htaccess, so I'd like to ask someone who does have how I should do the following.

these are some possible links:

```
root/alfa
root/alfa/?a=1&b=4
root/beta/?c=0
```

I would like those links to show as:

```
root/alfa/
root/alfa/?a=1&b=4
root/beta/
```

And I would like to redirect like this:
One of the problems I encounter is that with the trailing slash, the index doesn't find my CSS-file anymore.

```
root/index.php?uri=alfa
root/index.php?uri=alfa&a=1&b=4
root/index.php?uri=beta&c=0
```

Please help me out with some htaccess code since there are so many possible `RewriteCond`s and `RewriteRule`s out there I don't know which one is I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

- For css/js use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
- OR You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Isn't there a way to keep using relative paths for links? Also, with the `<base>` it doesn't work.

Comment: Always better to use absolute links when using pretty links.